# Binding repeater to a record?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, linq

I need to bind repeater with some structure that has only a record. Data table is already populated. I tried to bind it with a datarow or datarowview but it do not allow to do. Any suggestion please ?

Can I use Linq query for that ? If so can you please guide me the query for selecting first row of data table ?

Comment: can you show what you have tried? We don't know if you are using List<Entity> or DataTable or DataSet

Comment: codeingbiz, I mention I tried it with datarow and datarowview. I also have datatable populated.

Comment: You need to show your code. It would be easier to help based on what you have... I didn't downvote you anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
   Dim drList As New List(Of DataRow)
   drList.Add(myDataTable.Rows(0))  'add the first row in the datatable

   myRepeater.DataSource = drList
```

Comment: thanks, for replying. Is it mean a datarow cannot be used to bind a repeater ? or other databound controls ?

Comment: I can't confirm that right now but any class that implements IEnumerable can be databound - I don't know if `DataRow` implements IEnumerable or its subclasses